# DES and using the S-Box 1

Tags: des, s-boxes

Can someone please check my work and correct me if I am wrong, I am just starting to learn about DES. I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Show that `S1(x1) XOR S1 (x2) != S1(x1 XOR x2)`.
>    `x1 = 000000`, `x2 = 000001`

So, we get `S1(x1)` first: `00` is our row, and `0000` is our column which is `(0,0)` and in the `S1` Box table is the value `14`. `14` in binary is `1110`.

Now we get `S1(x2)`: `01` is our row, and `0000` is our column which is `(1,0)` and in the `S1` Box table is the value `0`. In binary, it's `0000`.

Now we XOR the two outputs:

```
    1110
XOR 0000
  = 0001
```

Thus, `S1(x1) XOR S1(x2) = 0001`.

Now we XOR `X1` and `X2` first:

```
     0000000
 XOR 0000001
  =  1111110
```

Now we lookup our output in the `S1` table: Our row is `10`, and our column is `1111` which is `(2,15)` and in the `S1` Box Table is the value `08` which is `1000`.

Thus, `0001 != 1000`. Is that correct? (And in case it isn’t, where did I take a wrong turn?)

Comment: Your XOR looks like XNOR.

Comment: In addition to using XNOR (which made you lookup from an incorrect input), it looks like you read the `S1`table at `(1,15)` rather than `(2,15)` as you wrote you would. And you did not detail how you split the 6 input bits into those for row and column. See page marked 14 of [FIPS 46-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips46-3/fips46-3.pdf#page=19) for theses important details.

Answer (score 1):

Your XOR equations are wrong.
You wrote:

```
    1110
XOR 0000
  = 0001
```

But it's not how the XOR works. `1 xor 0 = 1`, and in your example it somehow turns into `0` wich is an error. Reference the xor table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

So, the correct answer for `S1(x1) XOR S1(x2)` is:

```
    1110
XOR 0000
  = 1110
```

and for `x1 xor x2`:

```
    0000000
XOR 0000001
  = 0000001
```

Comment: `x1`, `x2`, and `x1 XOR x2` are bitstrings of 6 bits, not 7 bits as shown.